# Why is there a white bar above and below my iframe?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an iframe in an area that depicts rounded borders. In an effort to do this, I'm using an HTML table. My content displays as I want, but there is a white bar above and below the iframe. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:640px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:12px; width:12px; vertical-align:top; background-color:white; font-size:6pt;"><img alt="" src="c1.png" style="width:12px; height:12px; vertical-align:top;" /></td>
    <td class="height:12px; vertical-align:top;"><div style="background-color:silver; height:12x;">&nbsp;</div></td>
    <td style="height:12px; width:12px; vertical-align:top; background-color:white; font-size:8pt;"><img alt="" src="c2.png" style="width:12px; height:12px; vertical-align:top;" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:silver; font-size:6pt;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="background-color:silver; font-size:6pt;"><iframe id="myIframe" frameborder="0" style="border:0px; overflow:visible; width:100%;" width="100%" src="/Test.aspx" scrolling="no"></iframe></td>
    <td style="background-color:silver; font-size:6pt;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:silver; font-size:6pt;"><img alt="" src="c3.png" 
      style="width:12px; height:12px; vertical-align:bottom;" /></td>
    <td style="background-color:silver; font-size:6pt;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="background-color:silver; font-size:6pt;"><img alt="" src="c4.png"    
      style="width:12px; height:12px; vertical-align:bottom;" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can somebody tell me how to get rid of the white bars? Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: ya, it's look ok in chrome for sure and ie8.  Also, i can't tell if the broken images are messing it up or not, could you put your domain in there so the example loads correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your middle cell, your "text" (the non-breaking space) is taller than the row height should be.

Also, you have one `class` attribute instead of `style`.

Would this simplified code work for you? If I understand correctly what your intention is...

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width:640px;" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: silver; height:12px; width:12px;"><img alt="" src="c1.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></td>
    <td style="background-color: silver; height:12px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: silver; height:12px; width:12px;"><img alt="" src="c2.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: silver;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: silver;"><iframe id="myIframe" style="border: none; overflow:visible; width:100%;" src="/Test.aspx" scrolling="no"></iframe></td>
    <td style="background-color: silver;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: silver; height:12px; width:12px;"><img alt="" src="c3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></td>
    <td style="background-color: silver; height:12px;"></td>
    <td style="background-color: silver; height:12px; width:12px;"><img alt="" src="c4.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I put the word "test" in just before the iframe. the word "test" appears as I want. It has the silver background color. Then there is like a newline, then the iframe. The newline appears in white. There is also a newline after the iframe.

Comment: It's hard to tell without all the pictures and included page. Do you have a live preview of this somewhere online?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Firebug in Firefox (or the "Elements" developer tool in Chrome) to inspect your html elements and see which element is occupying that space.  It's also helpful for questions like these if you could list what browser(s) show the issue.  It's probably better suited to doctype.com as well.

Comment: I used Firebug and I put the word "test" in just before the iframe. the word "test" appears as I want. It has the silver background color. Then there is something like a newline, then the iframe. The newline looking area appears in white. There is also a newline type element after the iframe.

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).